# Find Height of Font In Twips

Tags: vb6

A quick question: how would I go about finding the number of Twips in a font size.

I am using a very simple dropdown listbox with code, but if anyone resizes or adjusts the form, the height of the drop in the listbox would be reduced/enlarged to accommodate the new font size.

I'm not sure why Microsoft ever thought that a IDE that thrives on a graphical interface should use Twips, but I really don't understand Microsoft.

If anyone has any insight, please . . . 
Thank you for your time,
Shawn

Comment: Twips are not the problem. This is not easier done in pixels.

Comment: 1 point = 20 twips.

Comment: 72 points = 1 in (25.4 mm) so 1440 twips = 1 in.

Comment: Twips are a logical thing and fonts come that way. Plus `ScaleMode` allows you to choose your own units. Twips, Points, inch (and metric), pixels, or character.

Comment: Fonts don't have a twips or pixel size.  Text has a size when rendered using a font.  So you might want to elaborate a bit more what you are looking for.  It be as simple as using `Form.TextWidth` and `Form.TextHeight`, but hard to say without more details.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I got sidetracked trying to adapt my idea to Java. - maybe next year. Thanks again. Shawn

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method to determine the height of the text:
Me.TextHeight("A")
Form.TextHeight("A")

**From help:**
Returns the height of a text string as it would be printed in the current font of a Form, PictureBox, or Printer
The height is expressed in terms of the ScaleMode property setting or Scale method coordinate system in effect for object. Use TextHeight to determine the amount of vertical space required to display the text. The height returned includes the normal leading space above and below the text, so you can use the height to calculate and position multiple lines of text within object.